# String Templating for object keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, template-literals

I'm getting eslint error  `Unexpected string concatenation.eslint(prefer-template)`

```
const listItemClasses = classNames({
          [' ' + classes[color]]: activeRoute(props, prop.layout + prop.path),
    });
```

How to fix this with template literals `` or shall I need to update eslint rule to allow this?

Comment: You need to replace `' ' + classes[color]` with `\` ${classes[color]}\``

Comment: classes[color].toString()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The eslint rule [`prefer-template`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template) expects you not to concatenate strings, and only use template strings.

In your case, you need to replace

```
' ' + classes[color]
```

with

```
` ${classes[color]}`
```

IIRC, eslint has an "auto-fix" flag for fixing that kind of error.

Also, the [eslint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) for Visual Studio Code has the auto-fix built-in.